# extracting body tags from smg file Beautiful Soup and Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an sgm file, with the following format:

```
<REUTERS TOPICS="NO" LEWISSPLIT="TRAIN" CGISPLIT="TRAINING-SET" OLDID="16321" NEWID="1001">
<DATE> 3-MAR-1987 09:18:21.26</DATE>
<TOPICS></TOPICS>
<PLACES><D>usa</D><D>ussr</D></PLACES>
<PEOPLE></PEOPLE>
<ORGS></ORGS>
<EXCHANGES></EXCHANGES>
<COMPANIES></COMPANIES>
<UNKNOWN> 
&#5;&#5;&#5;G T
&#22;&#22;&#1;f0288&#31;reute
d f BC-SANDOZ-PLANS-WEEDKILL   03-03 0095</UNKNOWN>
<TEXT>&#2;
<TITLE>SANDOZ PLANS WEEDKILLER JOINT VENTURE IN USSR</TITLE>
<DATELINE>    BASLE, March 3 - </DATELINE><BODY>Sandoz AG said it planned a joint venture
to produce herbicides in the Soviet Union.
    The company said it had signed a letter of intent with the
Soviet Ministry of Fertiliser Production to form the first
foreign joint venture the ministry had undertaken since the
Soviet Union allowed Western firms to enter into joint ventures
two months ago.
    The ministry and Sandoz will each have a 50 pct stake, but
a company spokeswoman was unable to give details of the size of
investment or planned output.
 Reuter
&#3;</BODY></TEXT>
</REUTERS>
```

There are 1000 records with root node RETURNS in the same file. i want to extract the body tag from each record and do some stuff on it but , i am unable to do that . following is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,SoupStrainer
f = open('dataset/reut2-001.sgm', 'r')
data= f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
topics= soup.findAll('body') # find all body tags
print len(topics)  # print number of body tags in sgm file
i=0
for link in topics:         #loop through each body tag and print its content 
    children = link.findChildren()
    for child in children:
        if i==0:
            print child
        else:
            print "none"
            i=i+1

print i
```

The problem is that the for loop does not print the contents  of body tag - instead it prints the record itself.

Comment: `print child.text` instead of `print child`

Comment: @imkost tried child.text but instead of giving me contents in body tag it gives me content of all tags one by one

Comment: of course. It is exactly what you print in your code. I've tried print `body`'s content, but there is a strange thing. Seems like you are not supposed to use name `body`. See my answer for code that works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've said in comment, by unknown (for me) reason, you are not supposed to name tag as `body`.

So, first step: replacing `body` tag name with, for example, `content`:

```
<REUTERS TOPICS="NO" LEWISSPLIT="TRAIN" CGISPLIT="TRAINING-SET" OLDID="16321" NEWID="1001">
<DATE> 3-MAR-1987 09:18:21.26</DATE>
<TOPICS></TOPICS>
<PLACES><D>usa</D><D>ussr</D></PLACES>
<PEOPLE></PEOPLE>
<ORGS></ORGS>
<EXCHANGES></EXCHANGES>
<COMPANIES></COMPANIES>
<UNKNOWN> 
&#5;&#5;&#5;G T
&#22;&#22;&#1;f0288&#31;reute
d f BC-SANDOZ-PLANS-WEEDKILL   03-03 0095</UNKNOWN>
<TEXT>&#2;
<TITLE>SANDOZ PLANS WEEDKILLER JOINT VENTURE IN USSR</TITLE>
<DATELINE>    BASLE, March 3 - </DATELINE><CONTENT>Sandoz AG said it planned a joint venture
to produce herbicides in the Soviet Union.
    The company said it had signed a letter of intent with the
Soviet Ministry of Fertiliser Production to form the first
foreign joint venture the ministry had undertaken since the
Soviet Union allowed Western firms to enter into joint ventures
two months ago.
    The ministry and Sandoz will each have a 50 pct stake, but
a company spokeswoman was unable to give details of the size of
investment or planned output.
 Reuter
&#3;</CONTENT></TEXT>
</REUTERS>
```

And here is code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,SoupStrainer
f = open('dataset/reut2-001.sgm', 'r')
data= f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
contents = soup.findAll('content')
for content in contents:
    print content.text
```

Comment: Any thought why the 'body' tag isn't recognized? Perhaps a bs4 anser to recognizing it?

Comment: My reply comes a whole life time later... but seeing as your post uses Python 2 syntax, I think it's worthwhile to mention that in Python 3 (Beautiful Soup 4.7), I'm able to simply do `soup.findAll('body')` and things work as expected. No need to rename `<BODY>` to `<SOMETHING_ELSE>`.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need the relevant parser (xml / lxml / html.parser / etc.).
I faced the same issue while extracting the HTML tags from SGML file using 'lxml' parser and solved it by changing the parser to 'html.parser'.

**Before**:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(file_content, 'lxml')
```

**After/Solution**:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(file_content, 'html.parser')
```

[Reference from the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers):

> There are also differences between HTML parsers. If you give Beautiful
> Soup a perfectly-formed HTML document, these differences won’t matter.
> One parser will be faster than another, but they’ll all give you a
> data structure that looks exactly like the original HTML document.
>
> But if the document is not perfectly-formed, different parsers will
> give different results.